# Send Battery Level from my Bluefruit Feather ESP32 through BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery

I am using [this demo](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/blob/master/examples/battery/battery.ino) from official docs from Bluefruit Feather BLE, so I have added inside the loop of my Arduino IDE as follows:

```
  float measuredvbat = analogRead(VBATPIN); // #define VBATPIN A9
  measuredvbat *= 2; // we divided by 2, so multiply back
  measuredvbat *= 3.3; // Multiply by 3.3V, our reference voltage
  measuredvbat /= 1024; // convert to voltage
  Serial.print("VBat: " ); Serial.println(measuredvbat);
```

I am getting values and I'd like to send the values over BLE but I think I should do it with another thread, because I have more code reading other received values, but I do not know the best way to do it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured out how to read it. I comment the issue in [this official thread](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51/issues/54)